# How to check a string and get the words with the special characters in python

Tags: python, search

I had a string like

```
"A collection point is a fancy name for what is essentially a dumpster
#Gazipur #issue #Garbage #Garbagecollection"
```

Here I needed to search only for the words with "#" and get those words into variables

I tried many ways.

Thank you

Comment: Please show some of the ways. Strategy: split on whitespace, loop over words, define "special characters".

Comment: @Nithin Can you clarify if you need the '#' symbol along with the words to be stored? Or just the words, taking out the hash symbol?

Comment: i had tried the all the answers and i had got the same output for all the answers which i wanted  thank for all for helping me

Comment: @code_byter thankq for helping me i don`t need the '#' symbol

Comment: @Nithinsaikumar But you ticked another answer :) Its ok. You can use mine if you need without the hash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Building on Akshay's answer, you could do:

```
import re

str1 = '#lol #loalsd asd'
r = re.compile('#(.*?)\s+')
m = r.findall(str1)
if m:
   hashtags = m
   print(hashtags)
```

The hashtags is a list, so you can access them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a *list comprehension* with the [`string.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) filter as:

```
>>> my_str = 'Gazipur #issue #Garbage #Garbagecollection'
>>> prefix = '#'

#                 filter words starting with prefix v
>>> [word for word in my_str.split() if word.startswith(prefix)]
['#issue', '#Garbage', '#Garbagecollection']
```

If you want to remove *prefix* from each word, you may slice the each string within your *list comprehension* expression as:

```
#           v slice string to remove the `prefix` 
>>> [word[len(prefix):] for word in my_str.split() if word.startswith(prefix)]
['issue', 'Garbage', 'Garbagecollection']
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OP was looking for the words without the hastag.

Comment: @code_byter Based on comment by OP *"i needed to search **only for the words with "#"** and get those words into variables"*. I think OP wants what I did :)

Comment: Wow, our interpretation is different then, I guess. Let's ask OP then.

Answer (score -1):

you could use reg ex.

```
import re
r = re.compile('#(.*?)\s+')
m = r.search(str1)
if m:
   hashtags = m.group(1)
```

EDIT:

Building on your answer, modify it to this:

import re

```
str1 = '#lol #loalsd asd'
r = re.compile('#(.*?)\s+')
m = r.findall(str1)
if m:
   hashtags = m
   print(hashtags)
```